# submit data from mutiple tabs usinf formik to redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk, formik

I have a bootstrap tab with two tabs. Both the tabs contain forms. I have a single Save button on top of the page.

I want to submit both the forms to backend using axios and redux-thunk on clicking the save button.

Any suggestions on best practice which will improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

Formik's [github repo](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/) has a lot of [helpful examples](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/tree/master/examples).

From what I get of what you're describing, this [MultistepWizard example](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/examples/MultistepWizard.js) could help.

You can pretty much keep the `Wizard` as it is and change the `App` component to yours.